# GCP: using VPC serverless connector and shared VPC in one cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vpc

I have two projects in GCP: HOST and APP
In HOST I have Shared VPC network 'shared' and subnet 'snet0'
In APP I have a redis instance, redis-network and Serverless VPC access (connected to the redis-network)

Now I need cloud run instance (in project APP) that has access to both: the subnet from HOST and the redis connector form APP.

I cannot use both in cloud run in the same time.

What is the best way to combine this?

Comment: You can't use both because it fails? Because you have a single connector and you need to access to 2 different VPCs?

Comment: So is it possible? Cloud run can get only one network, or only one connector

Comment: Yes, but you can bridge the VPCs